# Selectbox and Searchform and Custom Search Page

Tags: search

I'm in the very hard journey to make a Tire Website.

You know , Lots of Cars, Tires , Brands, An absolutely headache.

I'm using jigoshop as my main e-commerce plugin. and because is to difficult to filter attributes in jigoshop. I will use the simple search of wordpress for filtering words .

but if I use a select box like:

```
<form role='search' method='post' id='searchform' action='/'>
                            <label>A</label>
                            <select>
                                <option id="s" value="255">225</option>
                                <option id="s" value="230">230</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">235</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">240</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">245</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">250</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">260</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">265</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">270</option>
                            </select>


                            <label>At</label>
                            <select>
                                <option id="s" value="40">40</option>
                                <option id="s" value="45">45</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">50</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">55</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">60</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">65</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">70</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">75</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">80</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">85</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">90</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">95</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">100</option>


                            </select>

                            <label>Rin</label>
                            <select>
                                <option id="s" value="10">10</option>
                                <option id="s" value="11">11</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">12</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">13</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">14</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">15</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">16</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">17</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">18</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">19</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">20</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">21</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">22</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">23</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">24</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">25</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">26</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">27</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">28</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">29</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">30</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">31</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">32</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">33</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">34</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">35</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">36</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">37</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">38</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">39</option>
                                <option id="s" value="">40</option>
                            </select>

                            <input class='btn' value='Search' type='submit'/>
                        </form>
```

I don't get any result..

what is what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WPSE!

First of all - you cannot have two (or more) elements with the same ID. Second - your `select` elements lack `name` attribute and browser doesn't actually submit anything. Third - you cannot just expect to throw a bunch of selects into the form and expect everything to magically work. In order to even start searching, WordPress needs a query with `s` key - only then it will recognise the request as search and redirect to the appropriate search template.

As I said before, building a complex search system is not an easy task. You will probably need to hook into a [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action, detect if certain values have been submitted and modify the query accordingly. [Here's an article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) on how to build advanced queries using `WP_Query` class to get you started.

Comment: thanks for the answer , I think this will be a epic headach :D.

I found: http://fearlessflyer.com/2012/10/how-to-create-an-advanced-search-form-for-wordpress/

That is a good start point.... hope so.

Comment: this was the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484675/filling-input-text-with-select-options